# TIdSMTP : How to send special chars showing correctly in email body

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-2007, indy10

I'm on Delphi 2007, Indy version 10.6.1.5188.

When I send messages using my regular SMTP server and `TIdSMTP`, everything works fine.

But when I send using Amazon Simple Email Service SMTP (SES), all special chars in msg body, like `á`, `ç`, `é` are replaced for strange symbols like `¿½` and `�`.

What should I do to fix this issue, and why is it happening only when I use SES?

Here is my current code :

```
  idsmtp1.Host := 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com';
  idsmtp1.username := 'myusername';
  idsmtp1.password := 'mypassword';
  idsmtp1.Port := 587;
  idsmtp1.IOHandler := IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1;
  idsmtp1.usetls := utUseExplicitTLS;
  idsmtp1.UseEhlo := true;
  idmessage1.body.text := 'This is a test é á ó ç';
  with IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1 do
      begin
      SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
      SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
      SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
      end;
  idsmtp1.Connect;
  idsmtp1.Send(idmessage1);
```

And here is TIDMessage.savetofile contents :

```
From: "My Company" <myemail@mydomain.com>
Subject: Your subject
To: xxxx@hotmail.com.br
Bcc: myotheremail@mydomain.com
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Sender: My Company <myemail@mydomain.com>
Organization: My Organization
Date: Mon, 18 Nov 2019 09:19:05 -0300

VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Qgw6kgw6Egw7Mgw6cNCg==
.
```

Comment: Kind of hard to tell without any information related to sending the email. You're missing a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. You're not new here; you should know this before you posted.

Comment: Delphi 2007 is a pre-Unicode version of Delphi. It uses 8bit strings. You need to manually encode your data, such as to UTF-8, and then set the email's `CharSet` to match. Are you doing that? Please show your actual code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Nothing fancy in the code, is the same of my previous question, but i edited the question now with the code. Could you please tell me how do i set the charset and encode my message body ?

Comment: @delphirules see the answer I just posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi 2007 is a **pre-Unicode** version of Delphi, where all of the strings used in Indy are `AnsiString`. As such, you need to manually encode your email text to an 8-bit encoding, such as UTF-8, and then set the email's `ContentType` and `CharSet` properties to match, as well as the `ContentTransferEncoding` property so the UTF-8 bytes can pass through 7-bit email systems without losing data. For example:

```pascal
IdSMTP1.Host := 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com';
IdSMTP1.Username := 'myusername';
IdSMTP1.Password := 'mypassword';
IdSMTP1.Port := 587;
IdSMTP1.IOHandler := IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1;
IdSMTP1.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
IdSMTP1.UseEhlo := True;

IdMessage1.Body.Text := UTF8Encode('This is a test é á ó ç');

IdMessage1.ContentType := 'text/plain';
IdMessage1.CharSet := 'utf-8';
//alternatively
// IdMessage1.ContentType := 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';

IdMessage1.ContentTransferEncoding := 'base64';

with IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1 do
begin
  SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
  SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
  SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
end;

IdSMTP1.Connect;
IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
```

If you don't do this, then the email ends up being interpretted in other random charsets, such as US-ASCII, Windows-1252, etc which will not give you the results you want.

If you ever upgrade your code to Delphi 2009 or later, where all of the strings used in Indy are `UnicodeString`, you still need the `CharSet` assignment, but you can drop the manual `UTF8Encode()` call:

```pascal
IdSMTP1.Host := 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com';
IdSMTP1.Username := 'myusername';
IdSMTP1.Password := 'mypassword';
IdSMTP1.Port := 587;
IdSMTP1.IOHandler := IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1;
IdSMTP1.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
IdSMTP1.UseEhlo := True;

IdMessage1.Body.Text := 'This is a test é á ó ç';

IdMessage1.ContentType := 'text/plain';
IdMessage1.CharSet := 'utf-8';
//alternatively
// IdMessage1.ContentType := 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';

IdMessage1.ContentTransferEncoding := 'base64';

with IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1 do
begin
  SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
  SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
  SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
end;

IdSMTP1.Connect;
IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
```

Comment: Thanks, i did it, but now  the strange chars were replaced by another ones : where should be "ó" is showing "Ã³", and where should be 'ã', is showing 'Ã£'... Any hints ? Do i need to do something on idmessageInitializeISO ?

Comment: `ó` in UTF-8 is bytes `C3 B3`, when those bytes are misinterpreted as ISO-8859-1, Windows-1252, etc, the result is `Ã³`. Likewise, `ã` in UTF-8 is bytes `C3 A3`, which is `Ã£` when misinterpreted. So you are sending the correct bytes, they are just not being interpreted correctly by the reader. One thing I notice is that you are not setting a `ContentType` for the email. I have updated my answer to add that. As for the `OnInitializeISO` event, that is used only when encoding email *headers*, not when encoding *body text*.

Comment: Tried this, still have the problem... now on gmail accounts, all special chars are replaced by a ? mark. The strange thing is the subject line is reading ok, with the correct special chars...

Comment: @delphirules email headers and body text are encoded differently. You might try setting the `ContentTransferEncoding` property on addition to the `CharSet`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, tried this, but still, no luck :( The subject goes ok, but inside the body, 'á' becames 'Ã¡'. Anything else i could try ? Does it make difference to set idmessage1.charSet := 'utf-8' or 'UTF-8' ?

Comment: I've noticed a weird thing : after i call 'IdMessage1.Body.Text := UTF8Encode('This is a test é á ó ç');', in debug time this is what i see on Delphi's watch for the body's text : 'This is a test Ã© Ã¡ Ã³ Ã§' . Is this normal ?

Comment: @delphirules yes, that is normal, because the debugger in D2007 doesn't know anything about UTF-8, only ANSI. And that is what UTF-8 looks like when displayed as ANSI. And no, there is no difference between using `'utf-8'` vs `'UTF-8'` for the `CharSet`. Everything you describe suggests the email IS being encoded in UTF-8, so the problem has to be in the receiving end. Can you call one of the `TIdMessage.SaveTo...()` methods and then edit your question to show the content it produces?

Comment: Note it's say 'charset=us-ascii', but i've set IdMessage.charset to 'utf-8'... is that normal ?

Comment: @delphirules Are you setting the `ContentType` at all, like I showed? If so, are you setting it before or after setting the `CharSet`? In older versions, the `ContentType` has to be set first, otherwise it overwrites the `CharSet`. That was fixed recently. 10.6.1 is a bit old. Otherwise, you can set the charset on the `ContentType` itself, see the update to my answer.

Comment: This did the trick, indeed i was setting Contenttype after Charset ! Thank you very much ! Maybe i should update to the latest version, can i do it in D2007 without having problems with DataSnap ?

Comment: Remy, i really would like to thank you for your invaluable help during all these years (more than a decade actually). Everytime i had an issue with Indy components you always was very helpful and kind. I'd like to send some beers (or coffees if you wish) to your paypal account, can i ? :-D